# Why SQL CRUD take a long time in ADO.NET C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

In my project (Desktop Application - C#), I have used ADO .NET to communicate with SQL Server.

Unfortunately, some queries are very slow when run for the first time! But from the second time onwards, it has a high speed! When the queries are executed for the first time, they may take up to 30 seconds!

This happens for update, insert, delete and select. The corresponding tables either have about 10 records or they may have 700 records.

For example, I have a table with 394 records. No relationship and nothing. Just a simple table!

When I executed the following stored procedure, I saw in SQL Server Profiler that it took 29 seconds.

```
EXEC [bot].[sp_GroupStatisticsUserDailyMessages] 
           @Where = N'GroupId = 5000 AND LogDateTime >= ''4/14/2023 3:15:09 PM'' ',
           @OrderBy = N''
```

Or 37 seconds for the following update command in a table that has only 9 records:

```
UPDATE bot.tb_GroupStatistics 
SET CheckedMessagesCount = CheckedMessagesCount + 1, 
    GroupLastActivity = @GroupLastActivity 
WHERE GroupId = @GroupId',N'@GroupLastActivity datetime,@GroupId bigint',@GroupLastActivity='2023-04-29 13:10:46.633',@GroupId=5000
```

Before executing any command, I have also executed this command

```
SET ARITHABORT ON
```

Also, sometimes executing a simple select command for an empty table may take 9 seconds!

My connection string:

```
data source=.\sql2008;initial catalog=DB1;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=N6y;Connection Timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Max Pool Size=50000;Pooling=True;
```

Here's my code:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    string query = "A SIMPLE UPDATE COMMAND! LIKE UPDATE [TABLE] SET A=B";

    query = "SET ARITHABORT ON; " + query;

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
    {
        cmd.Connection = connection;

        if (queryBuilder.SqlParameters != null && queryBuilder.SqlParameters.Count > 0)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(queryBuilder.SqlParameters.ToArray());
        }

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            recordsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.LogWrite(ex, $"Msg: {query}");
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }

        return recordsAffected;
    }
}
```

I want to know what caused the execution of a simple update or any of the insert, delete, select commands to be long for the first time, but it is done quickly the next time?

Also keep in mind that if we don't use the query for a few hours, it will be very slow when it runs again! But by running it again, it is done at a very high speed.

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 (I know it's very old version) on a VPS (Virtual private server)

Thank you for guiding me

> A very important point that I forgot to mention, the problem I
> mentioned above only happened on the virtual server and there is no
> such slow speed on my local computer! I also use SQL 2008 on my local
> computer.

Comment: Sounds like there might be some issues with your sql server. A good startingpoint for looking for general issues is using Brent Ozars scripts found at his website, a collection of stored procedures that checks common missconfigurations https://www.brentozar.com/first-aid/

I would first check AUTO_OFF, and maybe do some disk performance test using diskspd
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/policy-based-management/set-the-auto-close-database-option-to-off?view=sql-server-ver16

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/hci/manage/diskspd-overview

Comment: The session wait stats should tell you why the first request took more time. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-session-wait-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Do you have `AUTO_CLOSE` set to `ON` for the database configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Slow has a lot of reasons

1.The index in the table 2.space table 3.issue Resource, server and network
4.Datatypes table 5.The current querys of the server causes blocking
6.performance proc 7.wait stats 8.etc

The reason of first time execution is slow include:

first time creates a plan and stores it in the buffer pool so that the plan can be reused when it executes next time and you run the query it may be using data that is on disk.

[MoreExplain](https://littlekendra.com/2016/11/25/why-is-my-query-faster-the-second-time-it-runs-dear-sql-dba-episode-23/)